# 2D flow simulation over a surface

Tags: modeling, workflow, fluid-simulation

I'm very new to blender but keen to learn more. I have used a lot of 2 and 3D modelling packages as well as a number of GIS applications.

I'm just trying to work out if I can model a fluid flow over a surface, ie a DTM (digital Terrain model) which I understand needs impotent as a tiff or similar image file.

What I want to do is simulate flood water across a surface/DTM.

If so, is there somewhere that would help me get started?

Comment: Will you add more to your question, making it more specific? Also when you say DTM do you mean "demographic transition model"?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you mean by *flow*, but maybe this answer will help you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26048/1853

Comment: Blender has no built in support for most of the formats used in GIS software. DEM, DTMs and other  geo-referenced formats need to bee converted to somehting blender can  read. If you can get Elevation Maps as Tiff, JPEG or PNG then you can use those to displace a plane to recreate terrain elevation. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27451/landscape-topography-from-grayscale-image

Answer (score 2):

Starting with a landscape.

[image]

Place a plane where your water should be.

[image]

(It doesn't have to be that big I just made it big for clarity, all you need is the plane to be as big as the water surface.)

In Edit Mode **subdivide** the plane.

[image]

Add a **subdivision Surface** modifier and a **Displace** modifier.

In the display modifier select **Texture**. (A new one will be created if there are none)

**Assign the texture** to be used as displacement. I used a wood Texture, but it's up to you how you want the water to flow.

Play with the **Strength** settings to get the right height for the displacement.

[image]

[image]

To animate the displacement.

**Create an Empty** and add a couple of keyframes for the motion.

[image]

On the displace modifier set the **Texture coordinates** as **Object** 
and Assign the Empty as the object.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A different way to do this in a less computationally-intensive way is not using a displacement for the geometry, but simulating the displacement on the plane.

On the material node use a Texture and connect it to the displacement input.

[image]

[image]

And animate the texture coordinates to simulate the water flow.

[image]

[image]