# Making a stream in Blender

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm trying to make a stream in blender. I have the stream bed with an applied displacement modifier, and an applied solidify modifier. I tried to use the fluid simulation, but it doesn't look the best. Any ideas?
[image: First Part of domain settings]

[image: Second Part of domain settings]

[image: Ground settings]

[image: Inflow Settings]

[image: Outflow Settings]

[image: Domain size]

Comment: Please add a screenshot with the settings.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28802/2d-flow-simulation-over-a-surface/28837#28837

Comment: I'm looking for more of a 3d approach.

Comment: looks like you have too much liquid in the bed, that's all. If you are unsatisfied how the water behaves, it's all in the simulation setting and can be adjusted. You are doing it right.

Comment: Is there a better/other way to adjust the amount of water other then scaling the inflow object?