# Low Poly Water Animation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers

I want to make a low-poly water animation, so I've subdivided and displaced this face to make it look like water:

[image: Water Surface]

Now, I want to animate it, like they do in this video:

https://youtu.be/oiX_0QLLDA0?t=55s

Also this:

https://youtu.be/oiX_0QLLDA0?t=1m22s

I tried a wave modifier, but that moves the entire object. Can I just make the individual vertices go up and down separately to create a water effect?

Comment: You can use an empty to control the texture for displacement: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28836/1853

Comment: You could use a lattice modifier with shape keys to simulate the effect. It might be that there's an easier solution though.