# Bending a group of objects?

Tags: modifiers, groups

How to bend (or add any other deforming modifiers to) a group of objects as at one solid object? Just for example this car animation (URL attached). It is good to keep wheels and lights, interior, and the body of the car as separate objects, but at the same time, they are deforming as one object. Any suggestions?

[image]

[Click here, to open animation of the example](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=334425757714591)

Comment: Use a lattice https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/lattice.html?highlight=lattice and a latice deform modifier on the object

Comment: Exactly what susu said, but add the lattice modifier on all objectS :)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26023/in-blender-3d-is-there-any-function-like-flow-along-surface-in-rhino-3d